# Entity Framework: Inheritance with same name for parent and child primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I am trying to make Entity Framework inheritance between two tables.

The parent:

```
ParentTable
  Id: int primary key
  CustomAttribute: int
```

The Child:

```
ChilTable
  Id: int primary key (not the same one as the parent, Child specific Id)
  TCId: int foreign key to parent
  SomeInformation: String
```

For some reasons I want to keep naming "Id" the primary key of both the ParentTable and the ChildTable. That should not bother EntityFramwork as I created a custom property with another name "CId" for the child Table:

[image]

And the Child1 table mapping is the following:

[image]

But when I "Validate" the model, VS2010 says...:

```
Error 3002: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 103:Potential runtime violation of table Child1's keys (Child1.Id): Columns (Child1.Id) are mapped to EntitySet Parents's properties (Parents.CId) on the conceptual side but they do not form the EntitySet's key properties (Parents.Id).
```

Basically, I understand that Entity Framework sees a problem in the fact we map a table's primary key to a property that's not the key of the Entity but then how are we supposed to use inheritance?

IS inheritance only allowed when there is no primary key in the "Child" table? Should I but my primary key as "simple key"?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: hmm... Parent.ID -> Primary Key, ok, and Child.Cid ? what's that? why do you need another ID? when you generate db by EF, u'll get 2 tables; Parent (Id,CustomAttribute) and Parent_Child1(Id[same like Parent.Id],SomeInformation). one of the advantages is, if you have more than only one inheritance from Parent, you can access easily with _entities.Parent.TypeOf<Child1>.SingleOrDefault(s....)

Comment: In my DB schema, "Id" in the child table and in the parent table is not aimed to be the same. The FK from the child to the parent is called "TCId". I am not generating DB from EF. I am generating EF from DB.

Comment: u've edited the model, now its clear! you can have only ONE primary key for each table,and because Child1 is a child, it has already a primary key(Parent.Id), except you create [composite primary keys](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx)

Comment: I actually have only one primary key. And I'd want it to be Id (Child.Id), not TCId (reflection/FK to Parent.Id).

I do not see why EF wants the primary key of the Child table to be the one which is also the FK to the PK of the Parent. From a DB design PoV there is no meaning for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF expects the child's `Id` PK to also be a FK to the parent. So `Child.Id` is both a PK and an FK.

Comment: Child.Id is not a FK to the parent, the FK to the parent is TCId... Maybe you did not see my edit.

Comment: @Undo: Well, I didn't see your edit since you made it an hour after my answer. However: You may want to re-read the answer. I am showing you the way which works. I understand what you are trying, but that way doesn't work.

Comment: I would not say "does not work" but more "EF is not able to handle this case [yet?]."... Kind of limitation of the framework. (I found at least another one btw - join table for Many to OneOrZero relationships...)